# Configure Upsource to inspect PHP

Tags: phpstorm, upsource

Upsource supports inspections and I am trying to configure them.

I have created the `Project_Default.xml` file under git.

How do I go about inspecting PHP code in upsource?

Answer (score 3):

You also need to make sure you have PHP installed on the server where Upsource is and configure Code Intelligence in your project's settings. Here's the documentation.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/creating-a-project-code-intelligence.html

**TLDR**: In Project's settings go to "Code Intelligence" tab, check "Enable Code Intelligence", check "Run inspections" and specify which PHP version your project's using.

Comment: Still doesen`t  work. php is 7.1 on the upsource server http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/6503/etoqtw.png  http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/3209/8EmgWs.png http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/8/3K0RPc.png

Comment: @funivan This is weird and looks like a bug. I'd suggest to contact support or to file a ticket in the issue tracker so that the team could fix it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/UP